# Expand/Collapse all jquery

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have the following jquery that can expand and collapse sections on my page.
It will also remember which section was last expanded and apply that when the page is reloaded.

What I want to do, is to have add a 'Expand All' and 'Collapse All' link to my page, but I'm not sure how the script should look like?  Any assistance?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    $(".toggle").hide();                                       //Hide .toggles

    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.toggle').not(':hidden').prev('.trigger').trigger("click");
    });

    $('.trigger').each(function () {                           //For each .trigger
        var theActive = $.cookie($(this).attr('id'));          //Retrieve the cookies
        if (theActive) {                                       //Verify if cookies exist
            $('#' + theActive).next(".toggle").slideDown(0);   //And slide down the respective .toggle
        }
    });

    $(".trigger").toggle(                                      //Toggle permits alternate clicks
   function () {
   $(this).next('.toggle').slideDown('slow');                  //On odd clicks, .toggle slides down...
   $.cookie($(this).attr('id'), $(this).attr('id'));           //...and the cookie is set by its ids.
   }, function () {
   $(this).next('.toggle').slideUp('slow');                    //On even clicks, .toggle slides up...
   $.cookie($(this).attr('id'), null);                         //...and the cookie is deleted.
   });
});
```

Section 1

```
<div class = "toggle">
  Some stuff
</div>    
<h3 class = "trigger" id="H1">Section 2</h3>
<div class = "toggle">
  More stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Try this ..http://designgala.com/how-to-expand-collapse-toggle-div-layer-using-jquery/

Comment: You can have some hidden variable and put the last item clicked and action in value. Like '#h1; expand'. Then on ready event check the hidden value and parse with ';' separator and call slideDown /slideUp based on condition

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, the toggle class is the section you wish to expand, so doing

```
$(".toggle").slideDown();
```

should slide down all elements with the class toggle. Use slideUp for the collapse all button.

Comment: sounds simple enough.  I initially thought I have to do every section on its own, but obviously not.  Will try it out.

Comment: Not yet.  I did not spend to many hours on it.  Sure I'm just missing something obvious.